# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

What am I doing wrong here? Imported random

```
from random import randint 
for i in range(5): 
    print(random(1,5))
```

---

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 5):

You are calling the module, but you should be calling the function from that module:

```py
from random import randint 
for i in range(5): 
    print(randint(1,5))
```